# MS Graph Using multiple search paramenters

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use multiple search parameters, but every time I test it out in the Graph Explorer it seems to ignore the search parameters completely. Only if I have one search parameter does it work for that specific search, but I need to pull emails that have attachments and were received yesterday.

This is what I've been trying to get to work:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$search="hasAttachments:true" AND "received:yesterday"&$expand=attachments
```

What is the proper format to search for emails with attachments and received yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole search query should be inside quotation marks `"hasAttachments:true AND received:received:yesterday"`

Your search query is separated to `"hasAttachments:true"` and `"received:yesterday"`

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$search="hasAttachments:true AND received:2022-09-15"&$expand=attachments
```

Comment: So simple, yet has been causing me headache today. Thank you very much for showing me the light.